# Create custom Predicate with Set<String> and String as parameter

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, functional-interface

I have a `String` as "ishant" and a `Set<String>` as ["Ishant", "Gaurav", "sdnj"] . I need to write the Predicate for this. I have tried as below code, but it is not working

```
Predicate<Set<String>,String> checkIfCurrencyPresent = (currencyList,currency) -> currencyList.contains(currency);
```

How can I create a `Predicate` which will take `Set<String>` and `String` as a parameter and can give the result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) which you're currently using represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) **of one argument**.

You're looking for a [`BiPredicate<T,U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) which essentially represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) **of two arguments**.

```
BiPredicate<Set<String>,String>  checkIfCurrencyPresent = (set,currency) -> set.contains(currency);
```

or with method reference:

```
BiPredicate<Set<String>,String> checkIfCurrencyPresent = Set::contains;
```

Comment: How to call this predicate within in the code? I am using this code boolean isCurrencyCodeValid =  requestCurrencyCodes.stream()
                    .noneMatch(checkIfCurrencyPresent(currencyValues,requireCurreny));

Answer (score 8):

If you were to stick with using `Predicate`, use something similar as :

```
Set<String> currencies = Set.of("Ishant", "Gaurav", "sdnj");
String input = "ishant";
Predicate<String> predicate = currencies::contains;
System.out.print(predicate.test(input)); // prints false
```

The primary difference between the `BiPredicate` and `Predicate` would be their `test` method implementation. A `Predicate` would use

```
public boolean test(String o) {
    return currencies.contains(o);
}
```

and a `BiPredicate` would instead use

```
public boolean test(Set<String> set, String currency) {
    return set.contains(currency);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aomine's answer is complete. using of `BiFunction<T, U, R>`  is another way:

```
BiFunction<Set<String>,String,Boolean> checkIfCurrencyPresent = Set::contains;
```