# How to use BiPredicate with anyMatch()

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

I have a Set of Currencies as `Set<String>` and RequiredCurrency as `Set<String>` . I have to check if any of required currency is present in currency set or not . I have written `BiPredicate` for that as below and trying to use the same in `anyMatch()` . But it is not working for me. How can i achieve it .

```
Set<String> currencyValues = currencies.getCurrencies().values()
                    .stream()
                    .map(currencyEntity -> {
                       return currencyEntity.getNameOfSymbol();
                    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<String> requestCurrencyCodes = globalPricingRequests.stream().map(globalPricingRequest -> {
    return globalPricingRequest.getCurrencyISOCode();
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());

BiPredicate<Set<String>, String> checkIfCurrencyPresent = Set::contains;

boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = requestCurrencyCodes.stream().anyMatch(checkIfCurrencyPresent.test(currencyValues));
```

I am unable to pass the requestCurrencyCode in `checkIfCurrencyPresent.test(currencyValues)`.

Comment: `Stream.anyMatch` takes a `Predicate`, not a `BiPredicate`. That said, using `anyMatch(currencyValues::contains)` should fit your needs.

Comment: `anyMatch` get `Predicate` as argument. so you should pass `Predicate` instead `BiPredicate`

Comment: This was the exact reason why I suggested **if** you need a `Predicate`, [how you could use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54040692/1746118). So precisely, you just needed a `Predicate` in your current use case and not a `BiPredicate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though ideally I would as well have [preferred using **`Predicate`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040486/create-custom-predicate-with-setstring-and-string-as-parameter/54040692#54040692) here, yet if you were to make a generic method that could be used in multiple situations, you could have spared yourself from the *wrapping up of `BiPredicate` within a `Predicate`* using the following utility method:

```
private static boolean checkIfCurrencyPresent(Set<String> set, String currency) {
    return set.contains(currency);
}
```

and then consumed it using a lambda as :

```
boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = requestCurrencyCodes
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(a -> checkIfCurrencyPresent(currencyValues,a));
```

such that it doesn't rely on testing a string against a specific `Set` and you could use it generically enough as:

```
boolean isCurrencyCodeValidInverseExample = currencyValues // any collcetion of string
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(a -> checkIfCurrencyPresent(requestCurrencyCodes, a)); // different set as an input
```

---

***Aside***: The first two lines of your code could possibly be made more readable as something like(assuming model names) :

```
Set<String> currencyValues = currencies.getCurrencies().values()
        .stream()
        .map(CurrencyEntity::getNameOfSymbol)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<String> requestCurrencyCodes = globalPricingRequests.stream()
        .map(GlobalPricingRequest::getCurrencyISOCode)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `BiPredicate`. Rather a simple `Predicate` would do it.

```
Predicate<String> checkIfCurrencyPresent = currencyValues::contains;

boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = requestCurrencyCodes.stream()
        .anyMatch(checkIfCurrencyPresent);
```

And here's a more condensed version.

```
boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = requestCurrencyCodes.stream()
        .anyMatch(currencyValues::contains);
```

Comment: What if i want to use a Bipredicate ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) method takes a `Predicate`, not a `BiPredicate`. Therefore you cannot use a `BiPredicate` directly with `anyMatch`. From the code you've shown you don't need a `BiPredicate` anyway. Just do:

```
boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = requestCurrencyCodes.stream()
        .anyMatch(currencyValues::contains);
```

If you really want to use a `BiPredicate` for some reason you can do:

```
BiPredicate<Set<String>, String> checkIfCurrencyPresent = Set::contains;
boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = requestCurrencyCodes.stream()
        .anyMatch(code -> checkIfCurrencyPresent.test(currencyValues, code));
```

However, I don't know why you'd want to do that. All it does is wrap a `BiPredicate` in a `Predicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the good answers provided so far. you can accomplish the said requirement via `Collections.disjoint`:

```
boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = !Collections.disjoint(currencyValues, requestCurrencyCodes);
```

`isCurrencyCodeValid` will be true if any value in `currencyValues` is present in `requestCurrencyCodes` otherwise false.

Full code:

```
Set<String> currencyValues = currencies.getCurrencies().values()
                              .stream()
                              .map(CurrencyEntity::getNameOfSymbol)
                              .collect(toSet());

Set<String> requestCurrencyCodes = globalPricingRequests.stream()
        .map(GlobalPricingRequest::getCurrencyISOCode)
        .collect(toSet());

boolean isCurrencyCodeValid = !Collections.disjoint(currencyValues, requestCurrencyCodes);
```